# Java gRPC server inbound vs outbound threads

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, server, grpc

So I have this grpc Java server:

```
@Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "shutdown")
public Server bodyShopGrpcServer(@Autowired BodyShopServiceInt bodyShopServiceInt) {
    return ServerBuilder.forPort(bodyShopGrpcServerPort)
        .executor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(12))
        .addService(new BodyShopServiceGrpcGw(bodyShopServiceInt))
        .build();
}
```

..and this client:

```
long overallStart = System.nanoTime();
int iterations = 10000;
List<Long> results = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(bodyShopGrpcThreadPoolSize);
ManagedChannel channel =
    InProcessChannelBuilder.forName("bodyShopGrpcInProcessServer")
        .executor(executorService)
        .build();
BodyShopServiceGrpc.BodyShopServiceStub bodyShopServiceStub =
    BodyShopServiceGrpc.newStub(channel);

for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
  long start = System.nanoTime();
  StreamObserver<MakeBodyResponse> responseObserver =
      new StreamObserver<>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(MakeBodyResponse makeBodyResponse) {
          long stop = System.nanoTime();
          results.add(stop - start);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
          Status status = Status.fromThrowable(throwable);
          logger.error("Error status: {}", status);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {}
      };
  bodyShopServiceStub.makeBody(
      MakeBodyRequest.newBuilder()
          .setBody(CarBody.values()[random.nextInt(CarBody.values().length)].toString())
          .build(),
      responseObserver);
}

channel
    .shutdown()
    .awaitTermination(
        10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
long sum = results.stream().reduce(0L, Math::addExact);
BigDecimal avg =
    BigDecimal.valueOf(sum).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(iterations), RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);
long overallStop = System.nanoTime();
```

This gives me average round-trip latency and overall time for a batch of 10000.
Now what bothers me is that latency is ~30-50% of overall batch time.

I assume this is because all of the server threads are being assign to serve client requests and there's no thread left in the pool to serve callbacks.

Is there a way how to tune this? I mean, it's not possible to set a different thread pool for requests and callbacks.

I know there's a streaming API in grpc, is that a preferred/only way to reduce round-trip latency?

Comment: You start all the RPCs in parallel, so the expected amount of time for the average response latency will be 50% of the total time spent. The very first RPCs will have very low latencies and the last RPCs will have very high latencies, since most of the time they were stuck in the executor queue. If the latency reduces, the total time spent reduces. Your results align with my expectations based on "how the math will work out."

Answer (score 1):

Thx @Eric Anderson it did not occur to me.
Plotted the results and you're absolutely right:
[latency plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjL4r.png)

My assumption that callback is waiting for an available thread was wrong, it's just that all the requests enter the system at the same time - start measuring at the same time. In fact I was comparing sync. vs. async. values, while this was working for sync. calls for async. it's clearly wrong.